# Initialise object in method - MQL5

Tags: c++, mql5

I want to initialise an object inside a method.

My code:

```
void OnTick()
{
  CBullishTrend *Bullish=NULL;
  CalcBullish(Bullish);
}
void CalcBullish(CBullishTrend &pBullish)
{
  pBullish = new CBullishTrend(ColorForBullishTrend);
  // do calculations
}
```

I get this compile error:

> '=' - object required

I can only pass objects by reference, so why am I getting this compile error?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think what u are trying to do is pass reference to a pointer, like so:

void CalcBullish(CBullishTrend *&pBullish)